# How to add a CGImageRef to a NSDictionary?

Tags: nsdictionary, cgimage

I have a CGImageRef variable and a CGRect (so no pointers) and I need to add it to an NSDictionary. Like an NSArray, NSDictionary-s only accept pointers. How can you add an CGImageRef or an CGRect anyway?

Answer (score 2):

CGImageRef is already a pointer, but it's not (AFAIK) a pointer to a valid Cocoa object. You can turn a CGImage into a Cocoa NSBitmapImageRep with `[[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:someimageref]`. And NSValue is there to wrap primitive types like CGRect.